# Unable to connect to Apache server in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, xampp

I have recently installed XAMPP to get all of my PHP and MySQL needs and am able to MySQL Database and ProFTPD; however, I am unable to connect to Apache Web Server (Picture below). The surprising part, the localhost page says it works. I am very new to this and willing to learn  more.

So far I have used [this site](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/) to base my fixes around but no dice.

I understand that there is another post that has an "answer", which I have tried, but it still doesn't let me connect to the Apache Web Server. Keep in mind, I am using a Macbook Pro with OS X version 10.11.4 (El Capitan). Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything else running on port 80, such as Skype?

Comment: Skype is currently closed, would it still give an issue if it is inactive?

Comment: It could be if it is still taking up the port. You could always configure Apache for a different port.

Comment: Ill give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: I have tried to configure the port to 8080 and still nothing.

Comment: without being able to look more closely at the install I'm afraid I cannot offer much more. I always use MAMP on my Macs (XAMPP on my Windows machines). Do a `netstat` from the console and see if anything else is conflicting.

Comment: So I tried uninstalling XAMPP and used MAMP and it works! Jay, thank you so much for all of your help - you are awesome.

Comment: Glad to be of help @Connexion! Good luck!